# cómo separo una cadena de caracteres en sus caracteres en python

Tags: python, string, lista

Intento separar una secuencia de ADN="ACTGGCATCA" etc, y colocarlos en una lista por pares, es decir:

Pares=[]

(el codigo que necesito)

Pares=[AC,TG,GC,AT,CA]

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código que has hecho hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar rebanado de listas, asi:

```
lista = [ADN[index:index+2] for index in range(0, len(ADN), 2)]
```

**Explicación**

`range(0, len(ADN), 2)` genera la secuencia (0, 2, 4, ...,), o sea, avance de a dos elementos dentro de la lista `ADN`.

`ADN[index:index+1]` es un rebanado que toma dos elementos a partir de `index`.

Finalmente, encerrando todo entre "[]", tenemos una nueva lista.

```
['AC', 'TG', 'GC', 'AT', 'CA']
```

Comment: Gracias, gracias, enserio muchas gracias. está ush el codigo.

Answer (score 1):

Trabajando con cadenas largas de ADN se debe evitar crear copias innecesarias si no quieres quedarte rápidamente sin memoria. Normalmente, trabajas sobre una parte de la cadena, para lo que funciona muy bien los *iteradores*.

Para convertir una cadena en un iterador se emplea la función `iter()`:

```py
ADN = "ACTGGCATCA"

it = iter(ADN)
```

El iterador va ofreciendo elemento por elemento hasta que se agota:

```py
print(next(it)) # --> 'A'
print(next(it)) # --> 'C'
...
print(next(it)) # --> 'C'
print(next(it)) # --> 'A'
print(next(it)) # --> ERROR
```

Para escoger de dos en dos --que es lo que quieres-- podemos usar dos veces el iterador:

```py
it = iter(ADN)

for (a, b) in zip(it, it):
    print(a, b)
```

Este bucle va recorriendo la cadena de dos en dos, sin gastar memoria en crear listas intermedias. Si aún así necesitas crear la lista, se puede hacer así:

```py
it = iter(ADN)

pares = ["".join(z) for z in zip(it, it)]
```

Si en lugar de pares necesitas grupos mayores, existe un truco. Para obtener grupos de `n` elementos se contruye una lista de iteradores como `[it]*n`, que no es otra cosa que una lista de `n` veces el mismo iterador `it`. Así podemos escribir una versión más general:

```py
it = iter(ADN)
n = 2

grupos = ("".join(z) for z in zip(*[it]*n))

for grupo in grupos:
    print(grupo)
```

¿Y qué pasa si el número de elementos de la lista no es múltiplo de `n`? En este caso el último grupo tendría menos de `n` elementos. Lo que hace `zip` es ignorar este *remanente*, por lo que se perdería. Un modo de evitarlo es usar la versión [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) del módulo `itertools`:

```py
import itertools

it = iter(ADN)
n = 7
default = '_'

grupos = ("".join(z) for z in itertools.zip_longest(*[it]*n, fillvalue=default))

print(next(grupos))  # -> ACTGGCA
print(next(grupos))  # -> TCA____
```

Te recomiendo que te mires los iteradores, sobre todos [las *recetas* que hay en la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) de [itetools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html)).

Comment: QUE NIVEL!!!!!!